# FTPClient.listnames() hangs when try to get list of files from server

Tags: android, ftp-client

I am trying to get the list of files from FTPserver.
My directory on server is "upload" directory, and i am trying to get the file name list from that directory using apache ftpclient library.

I connect to server successfully and login also successful but when the line ...

```
FTPClientOBJ.listNames(); // for root directory i tried this and
FTPClientOBJ.listNames("/upload/"); // for upload directory which is in root directory
```

comes, at that time process hangs and after some time(3-4 min) i am getting exception that says Connection Closed without indication.

I am trying to do this in android.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved the issuee ..
I was not enabling the passive mode thats why problem was occuring.

After enabling passive mode i solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user647953. Problem solved too with line 
`ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode(); `

added before `String [] liste = ftpClient.listNames();`